# How to change path variable in angular path so dogs/1/collar can become dogs/2/collar using the router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

dogs/1/collar could be dogs/1/diet so I can't hardcode it as dogs/ + id + /collar.

Is there a way for angular to tell me that my current route is dogs/1/collar
with path variable id:1 and then I say alright change the id to 2 and give me the new url?

Answer (score 0):

You can check which is your current route by using

```
public router: Router //in constructor input params

let myCurrentRoute = router.url;
```

And then you may write next steps as per your requirement.